# Efi/microsoft/boot/bootmgfw.efi not found after restarting laptop from windows update

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot, windows-update, dualboot

hi this may sound duplicating question but is different to all the other related to this.
I ran windows update for Cummalitive updates recently on my dual boot laptop.This failed while updating and i saw it was undoing the changes. Once this was complete i restarted the laptop then encountered *erorr Efi/microsoft/boot/bootmgfw.efi not found* and not able to boot into windows
I was able to fix this issue by booting windows from USB but in windows the update is still not complete so when i tried running windows update again i encountered the same issue with *erorr Efi/microsoft/boot/bootmgfw.efi not found*
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/may-11-2021-kb5003169-os-build-18363-1556-13896704-b003-4d24-bf45-b6e1ff506d64 this was the update that failed while updating and caused the error mentioned above.
Any way to resolve this as i never seen this before?
i added an image of my update history [MY_UPDATE_HISTORY](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02ivy.jpg)

[efi file not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx1xz.jpg)
[undoing changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02ivy.jpg)
[installing update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6AuTj.png)

Comment: @Ramhound it was a windows update Your device is missing important security and quality fixes. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/may-11-2021-kb5003169-os-build-18363-1556-13896704-b003-4d24-bf45-b6e1ff506d64

Comment: Do you have KB5001406 or KB5003244 installed?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting another comment

Comment: @Ramhound i have updated Question....i dont have either  KB5001406 or KB5003244 installed you can check my windows update history picture i have put a link to in qestion

Comment: Maybe you can try `Reset This PC` and opt for `Keep my files`. I have no idea how well it could go though. (You might lose program configuration or installation as well. Research about it yourself first in case you have nothing else to try.)

Comment: The not found error is apparently from grub btw. It still intrigue me why would the file be removed during the undoing process though, as that is doomed to make the installation unbootable. (Well, it could rely on the `EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi` copy, if it doesn't also remove it)

Comment: @Davertonator - You didn’t actually provide your Windows Update history, I strongly suggest you install KB5001406 since it’s required for all updates (including the one your attempting to install)

Comment: Why can’t you install it? The update specified by the article you linked to is actually required to install the patch your trying to install

Comment: @Ramhound ask windows update that ...it fails while updating i told you this already

Comment: You only said you had problems installing KB5003169.  You also never actually provided your Windows Update history. Its clear you are frustrated but if you point that frustration towards me I will just avoid the situation entirely.  I am trying to help you diagnose the problem.  You will have to provide the Windows Update logs in order to diagnose the reason Windows Update is failing (if that’s even the case).  Please avoid unnecessary commentary, any information necessary to diagnose your issue l, should be in the question not a comment

Comment: SetupDiag can diagnose the reason 20H2 failed to install.  We could also use the logs or generates